# c# process exiting immediately without running .exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm attempting to launch slui.exe for users not on our network so they can validate their Windows installations via our MAK key with a c# program, but the process will just exit immediately when compiled to an .exe; If I run the program in debug mode from VS 2010 it will run successfully, or if I launch the .exe on a machine with VS2010 installed it will also run successfully. My code looks like:

```
string path = Environment.SystemDirectory;
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path + "\\slui.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = 4;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

I've tried running process explorer and it doesn't show any processes beginning when I attempt to run this code.

Could there be something with .net?? I'm running .net 4 on both machines, so I didn't think that was the problem.

I'm really confused why this code will work fine on my development machine either in debug mode or compiled to an .exe, but not on other machines; I must be missing a dependency somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your development machine x86 and other machines x64?

Comment: Please post your true code, this one won't compile. Do you catch any exception?

Comment: When you run the .exe and it exits, look in the Windows event logs to see what, if any, exceptions may have occurred.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, the dev machine is x64, and it will run successfully in either debug mode, or the compiled .exe. If I run it on another machine with the same build, (minus Visual Studio 2010 installed), it will do nothing. I have the UAC popping, and I've tried using a Manifest file set to either "highestAvailable" and 'requireAdministrator" to no avail.

Comment: What does `p.Start()` return?

Comment: Hi David, p.start() returns 0.

Comment: Hi Adriano,  it was a type-O, p.start(); should have been p.Start();

Comment: How can it return 0? The return type is `bool`.

Comment: I just printed out:
p.ExitCode.ToString()

was this not the correct way to see what p.Start() is returning??

Comment: I added the code:

if(p.Start() == true)
   Message("got here"):
else
   Message("no"):

and it is returning true... and the exit code is returning 0, so I really don't see why it's not running...unless there's some dependency on the test machine I'm missing. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Ok... **update**... if I right-click on the executable and choose: 'Troubleshoot compatibility', it will bring up a compatibility box. I chose: 'Try recommended settings' and it applied the settings:

'Windows compatibility mode: Windows XP (SP 2)'

I then click: 'Start the program' and it will then launch successfully...

Does this make sense to anybody??? 

Thanks again to everyone for your help.

Comment: @user1360150 - It makes perfect sense.  The problem is likely a problem with the system configuration only you can figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Well, I would be extremely surprised if I was the only person that has ever come across an issue where a c# compiled .exe file will run on a machine with VS 2010, but not on a machine without VS installed but has the exact same machine configuration otherwise. There must be some dependency installed with VS that is allowing the file to run that the machine without VS is lacking.

Comment: **Update**

If I run this executable from a network share on the client machine it will work...but not when copied locally. I don't see any issues with the permissions on the file. I've read some things about caspol.exe, but that seems to relate to folder permissions and necessarily on file permissions on a local machine... banging my head against the wall on this one...

Comment: i have the same problem.. on debug my code start slui on exe without debug nothing =(

Answer (score 1):

Check the EventLog please, if the process crashes on startup it will be listed there.
A good example of your symptoms is if you try to start a process whose dependencies are not present for e.g.  (I.e. slui.exe references slui.dll and it can't find it).

Comment: No errors that I can see that are relating to this issue...either in the Application or the System logs... nothing referencing slui.exe.